# Insert one matrix after every row of another matrix in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have to matrices and would like to prepare some kind of list where second matrix is repeated after each row of first matrix. For the creation of matrices I used library "plyr". Here is the example:

```
library(plyr)
# first matrix
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c(1,2)
c <- c(1,2,3)
mat1 <- expand.grid(a= a, b= b, c= c)
mat1 <- mat1[order(mat1$a, mat1$b), ]
mat1

# second matrix
mat2 = matrix(data= c(rep(0, 9)), nrow= 3, ncol= 3) 
mat2
```

So the resulting txt file would look like this

```
a=1 b=1 c=1
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
a=1 b=1 c=2
0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0
a=1 b=1 c=3
....
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it like this:

```
tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
apply(mat1, 1, function(x) {
  df <- setNames(data.frame(mat2, check.names = FALSE), paste(names(mat1), x, sep = "="))
  write.table(df, file = tf, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
})
```

Comment: This looks promising. How can I see the resulting file? There are also some warnings "Warning messages: 1: In write.table(df, file = blank, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,  ... : appending column names to file". Is this OK?

Comment: `cat(tf)` (tf = temporary file) to see the path + filename, or `shell.exec(tf)` on Windows to open it with the application that is associated with the file extension. You can ignore the warning.